# Installing Ubuntu from FreeDOS

Tags: installation

Is it possible to install Ubuntu from FreeDOS? The machine does not have an optical drive, so I'm assuming I'll be able to install via memory stick. If so, what are the system requirements?
Thanks!
Chris

Comment: You can't install an operating system from an another operating system (with the notable exception of Wine). What you have to do is to prepare a USB drive with the Ubuntu installer and boot from it **instead of** booting into FreeDOS.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Wine doesn't install Windows, it's a Windows emulator.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: oops, sorry. I meant Wubi.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition), Ubuntu Desktop editions needs:

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better) 512 MiB RAM (system
  memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or4
- external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach) VGA capable
- of 1024x768 screen resolution Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for
- the installer media Internet access is helpful

Also, the system should be able to boot from the USB drive. (One can't install Ubuntu from FreeDOS, at least not easily)

But the best way to be sure is to try it (after the Ubuntu .iso is downloaded, it takes only a few minutes to create a Live USB)